# React: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error:

Actually, I am trying to change the button text for a few seconds when I click on the button.

This is basically for **Add To Cart** Button, I want to hold the button process for a few seconds for my API call in the same function.

My Code:

```
const AddToCart = async (sku) => {
    this.setState({ buttonText: "Loading..." });
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ buttonText: "Saved" });
    }, 5000);
  }

  const [value, setvalue] = useState([]);
  const initialState = "ADD TO CART";
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("ADD TO CART");



 render() {
    return (
        <a onClick={()=>{AddToCart(item.sku)}} className="add-to-cart-btn">
        <i className="fa fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>{buttonText}</a>
    );
 }

My Final code is what I am trying to do.

    const AddToCart = async (sku) => {
    this.setState({ buttonText: "Loading..." });

    const user_id = localStorage.getItem('card_id');
    let product_details = {
      sku_name: sku,
      qty: 1,
      quote_id: user_id
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ buttonText: "Saved" });
    }, 5000);

    dispatch(useraction.addtocartRequest(product_details));
  }
```

I am new to this technology. Any other suggestions also help me a lot.
Thank you very much for your consideration! :-)

Comment: how you are using `this.setState` in a functional component! You should use react hooks.

Comment: Can you please suggest to me, how I use the react hooks in the same?

Comment: check answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using `this.setState` which is used for class-based components but you are using functional-based component so instead of `this.setState` simply write `setButtonText('Loading...')`

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

you should use react hooks instead of `this.setState`, here how to do it:

```
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("ADD TO CART");
  // buttonText is value getter
  // setButtonText is value setter
```

so if you want to update the value of you state:

```
setButtonText(newValue)
```